# JStree Async Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree, jstree-search

Whe are busy building a web based app. And we inherited the code where the previous developers used jstree so now the whole site consist out of a tree that uses jstree.

Everything worked even the search on the tree, but then we came across a problem where certain tabs loaded too long because of the tree which was too big.

So we went and made the the tree async / lazy loading which works perfectly but know the problem is that the search doesn't work that well.

Because we made a api for the search which works but it doesn't do the call back after new tree has been loaded.

Can someone help because I've been struggling for 3 days now and its giving me a head ache.

```
    // Tree Search
searchAjaxFunction: function () {

        var TreeCustomApiRequest = {
            nTreeCustomDesc: document.getElementById("tree_search").value,
            nUserId: document.getElementById("TrendUserID").value,
            nAccessLevel: document.getElementById("hfTrendAccessLevel").value
        }  
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(TreeCustomApiRequest),
            url: 'api/TreeCustomSearch.aspx',
            success: function (jsonData)
            {
                Tree.dataJson = jsonData;

                // Clear the tree.
                //Tree.dataJson = jsonData;
                if ($("#tree").jstree()) {
                    $('#tree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = jsonData;
                    $('#tree').jstree(true).deselect_node(this);
                    $('#tree').jstree(true).toggle_node(this);
                    $('#tree').jstree(true).refresh();
                }
            },
            contentType: "application/json"
        }); 
},

onClickFunctionNode: function(node) {
    Tree.treeDivIdSelector.jstree(true).toggle_node(node);
},
pluginsArray: ["search", "checkbox", "types", "json_data","html_data"],
treeMenuContextItems: {},
Init: function(initData) {
    Tree.dataJson = initData.dataJson;
    Tree.treeDivIdSelector = initData.chartDivId;
    Tree.searchDivIdSelector = initData.searchDivId;
    var apiUriTree = 'api/TreeCustomChildren.aspx';
    Tree.treeDivIdSelector.jstree({
        "checkbox": {
            "keep_selected_style": true,
            "three_state": false
        },
        "plugins": Tree.pluginsArray,
        'core': {
            'data': function (node, cb) {
                // Fetch tree custom parent nodes
                if (node.id === "#") {
                    cb(Tree.dataJson);

                }
                else {
                    var _cb = cb;
                    //Fetch tree custom Child nodes


                    var TreeCustomApiRequest = {
                        nUserId: document.getElementById("TrendUserID").value,
                        nAccessLevel: document.getElementById("hfTrendAccessLevel").value,
                        nTreeCustomParentId: node.id
                    }
                    function recieveData(data) {
                        cb(data);
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(TreeCustomApiRequest),
                        url: apiUriTree,
                        success: recieveData,
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    });
                }
            },
            "themes": {
                "icons": false
            }
        },            


        "contextmenu": {
            items: Tree.pluginsArray.indexOf("contextmenu") > -1 ? Tree.treeMenuContextItems : null
        }

    });         

    var tree = Tree.treeDivIdSelector.jstree();
    function getNode(sNodeID) {
        return tree.get_node(sNodeID);
    }

    Tree.treeDivIdSelector.on('click', '.jstree-anchor', function(e) {
        Tree.onClickFunctionNode(this);
    }
    );
    //Tree.searchDivIdSelector.keyup(Tree.searchFunction);
},
```

The next code is in the client side......

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataJson = <%=sTreeViewJson%>
        Tree.Init({ dataJson: dataJson, chartDivId: $("#tree") });

        $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
            // Do the Ajax search
            Tree.searchAjaxFunction();
            //var value = document.getElementById("tree_search").value;
            //Tree.searchFunction();

    })
    });


</script>
```

Comment: And thank you in advance for any help...

Comment: Can you add a 'complete: function(jqXHR, status) {...}' callback to your AJAX to see what status you are getting from server? Because you could get an error and then your 'success' callback won't be called.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov I adde the jqXHR and status to my ajax with a alert(jqXHR.status); and after I run the tree I get undefined back.

Comment: What I want to do is as soon as the new tree has been generated it should be able to use the init function again but it never get into after the search refresh.

Comment: I do not see where you are calling `Init` function in your AJAX callbacks.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov Thank you that you pointed out I was never calling my Init function below is my fix.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nikolay, it was a stupid mistake from me so what I added was just this to my code:

```
success: function (jsonData, callback )
            {
                //Goes back to the Callback with the new search data
                Tree.Init({ dataJson: jsonData, chartDivId: $("#tree"), searchDivId: $("#tree_search") });
                $('#tree').jstree(true).refresh();
            }
```

So I removed the

```
                $('#tree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = jsonData;
                $('#tree').jstree(true).deselect_node(this);
                $('#tree').jstree(true).toggle_node(this);
```

Know it gets my data and refreshes the table with the init function while it has my new data.

Hope this also may help someone = ).